# How do I create an Event in a web form in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm a computer science student, and I'm in Web Applications right now. I know how to create an event in a WinForm (you just double-click whatever you want to make an event with) and I just don't know how to do it in a web form. I'm using Visual Studio 2012. say this is my control:

```
<asp:Button ID="playButton" runat="server" Text="Play" />
```

How do I create an event in the Form1.aspx.cs class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just attach the event handler yourself, rather than using the IDE to attach the event for you, regardless of what type of environment you're in:

```
SomeEvent += myEventHandler;
```

Where `myEventHandler` is a method that is of the proper signature.  If you type the above code Visual Studio will also provide an option to automatically generate a method of the appropriate signature for you if one does not already exist.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you're looking for is this:

In the code snippet you posted just add the attribute OnClick, like below:

```
<asp:Button ID="playButton" runat="server" Text="Play" OnClick="playButton_Click"/>
```

And inside your aspx.cs (codebehind) class you put the following code:

```
protected void playButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //put your code/logic here
}
```

There are a lot of examples on the internet for begginers on asp.net, just google a bit and you'll find a lot of sample codes (even in stack overflow).

Best regards.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another easy way to create the default event using the Visual Studio IDE:

1. Add a button to a page and view it via the 'Design' tab
2. Highlight the button to make it in focus (do steps 3 and 4, or skip to Option #2)
3. Look at the properties window and select the little lightning bolt button that represents the events for the control.
4. Double-click in the area to the right of **'Click'** to generate the default event.

Option #2: Just double click the button in the designer view to generate the event just as you you were used to in a WinForms application.

This will bring up the code window and you will be inside the event for the control you just selected.